# Python/Pandas - Merging dataframe with numpy array in a peculiar way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have this Dataframe:

```
                 Value        1lag        2lag        3lag        4lag
Date                                                                     
2005-04-01  258.682029  214.382786  270.163089  253.674453  216.587332   
2005-05-01  173.253998  258.682029  214.382786  270.163089  253.674453   
2005-06-01  244.432029  173.253998  258.682029  214.382786  270.163089
```

And I have this numpy.ndarray, called coef:

```
coef = [  1.40136101e-01   6.96820991e-02   2.95210824e-02  ]
```

I need to insert each of those values as a column, repeating the same value in all the lines, so it gets to look like this:

```
                 Value            Coef       1lag            Coef       2lag            Coef
Date                                                                     
2005-04-01  258.682029  1.40136101e-01 214.382786  6.96820991e-02 270.163089  2.95210824e-02
2005-05-01  173.253998  1.40136101e-01 258.682029  6.96820991e-02 214.382786  2.95210824e-02
2005-06-01  244.432029  1.40136101e-01 173.253998  6.96820991e-02 258.682029  2.95210824e-02
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `np.tile()` to get repeat your array `coef` as many times as you need:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.tile(coef, (len(df.index), 1)), columns=['Coef']*5)
```

This will create a DataFrame which you can merge into your existing one.